# how to see or print out what communication occurs at a particular port?

Tags: java, port, xml-rpc

Is there a way in Java or some software tool to see the communication that takes place at a particular port?  I have xml-rpc clients and servlets communicating with xml at a pro 2001 on my local machine and it seems my servlet is not receiving all the messages sent from the client.

Comment: Check out [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

Comment: I installed Wireshark, but cannot see how it can be used to solve the problem.  Perhaps, you could list the steps needed to be performed in Wireshark?

Comment: Well technically this question is already [offtopic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on StackOverflow, so you will need to figure that out on your own or ask a more specific question. Basically you install Wireshark and set it to intercept all traffic, then filter by port number.

Comment: how can I use it to filter xml-rpc traffic?  There is HTTP, but I don't see the xml-rpc option.

Comment: XML-RPC is nothing else but HTTP with XML content: [XML-RPC: an RPC mechanism using HTTP as the transport mechanism and XML as the marshalling mechanism](http://wiki.wireshark.org/RPC)

Comment: Okay!  Now I see!  Wow, that is very, very cool!

Comment: how can I recover the actual xml of the messages?

Comment: I need to listen to xml-rpc communication on localhost.  So, it seems Wireshark cannot handle this.  But Wireshark docs point to a program called RawCap.  Will try this out.

Comment: http://www.netresec.com/?page=RawCap this works for what I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wireshark is a very impressive tool.  But I needed to see the communication between a xml-rpc client and servlet running on localhost on a Windows machine and this is not supported by Wireshark.  However, RawCap does support this and I was able to use RawCap to see the actual xml-rpc traffic between my servlet and client.  It's a great tool.  I use the Wireshark UI to view the RawCap dump file.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a port forwarder in the middle.  This is my [choice.](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/g3/tcpproxy.html#port-forwarding-mode)

It will output to screen all of the traffic.